# Why vector don't equal when differentiating sin(pi*x)

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I don't understand why i keep getting

> Error using plot Vectors must be the same length

As the data shows s1=1X100 and s2=1X99 which i don't understand why it has that data.

```
clc;
%differentiation and integration:
%Waveform of sine(pi*x):

sym('x');
s= sin(pi*x1);
x1= linspace(0,4);

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x1,s)
axis([0 4 -4 4]);

subplot(2,1,2);
s1= diff(s);
plot(x1,s1) % Error at this line
```

Comment: Hi, you should read the documentation of `diff`: `If x is a vector of length m, then y=diff(x) returns a vector of length m-1`. One possible solution for your problem would be: `s1=[0 s1]`

Comment: The symbolic variable `x` is never used and `x1` is defined out of order. Please provide a Rundle example.

Comment: @Irreductible, this is actually the answer to the question, you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments

You should read the documentation of `diff`:

```
If x is a vector of length m, then y=diff(x) returns a vector of length m-1.
```

One possible solution for your problem would be:

```
s1=[0 s1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to substitute the value of *x* in the *sym* objects *s* and *s1* using ***subs***. After that it will be converted to double and then you can plot them.

```
syms x;
s= sin(pi*x);
x= linspace(0,4);
subplot(2,1,1);
sr = subs(s,x) ;
plot(x,sr);
axis([0 4 -4 4]);
subplot(2,1,2);
s1= diff(s);
s1r = subs(s1,x) ;
plot(x,s1r)
```

YOu need not to use *syms* actually.

```
x= linspace(0,4);
s= sin(pi*x);
subplot(2,1,1);

plot(x,s);
axis([0 4 -4 4]);
subplot(2,1,2);
s1= gradient(s);

plot(x,s1)
```

Comment: If that was the case, code would crash at the first plot attempt, not the second one